# How to regroup arrays in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have the PHP array like this

```
[
['name'=>'john0', 'order' => '1'],
['name'=>'john1', 'order' => '2'],
['name'=>'john2', 'order' => '2'],
['name'=>'john3', 'order' => '3'],
['name'=>'john4', 'order' => '3'],
['name'=>'john5', 'order' => '4'],
['name'=>'john6'],
['name'=>'john7', 'order' => '5'],
]
```

I want the following

1. Sort by order from ASC
2. If order is not there then that element should append to last
3. If order is same , then they should be grouped together in array

The result should be

```
['john0',['john1','john2'],['john3','john4'],'john5','john7','john6']
```

Comment: You can use `usort` to sort the array, then you'll have to write a loop to regroup everything -- there's nothing built in to do that.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it as follow

```
$aResultArray = array();
$aTempWithoutorder = array();
foreach( $aArray AS $array )
{
  if( isset( $array['order'] )
     $aResultArray[$array['order']][] = $array['name'];  
  else
    $aTempWithoutorder = $array;
}
ksort($aResultArray);
$aRearrange = array();
foreach( $aResultArray AS $iOrder=>$name )
{
  $aRearrange[] = $name;
}
$aFinalArray = $aRearrange + $aTempWithoutorder;

$aFinalArray will have order
```

Comment: $aArray will be your input array which you have defined in the question.